# Why I cannot start EXE with DynamicAssembly DLL?

Tags: object, dynamic, filenotfoundexception

I have a problem ...

I developed proxy class for creation dynamic DLL on runtime and use it in another project by adding in "references" in my project.
I write: VC 2010, .NET 4.0, C#.

```
public DynamicProxy(
        string nameModule,
        System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderAccess accessModule,
        string assemblyFileName = null,
        IEnumerable<System.Reflection.Emit.CustomAttributeBuilder> customAttributes = null)
{
    try
    {
        // module name
        m_AssemblyFileName = assemblyFileName;
        // try doing something
        AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        // create assembly
        m_MainBuilder = (customAttributes != null) ?
            domain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
            new System.Reflection.AssemblyName(nameModule) { Version = new Version("6.11.395.0610") },
            accessModule,
            customAttributes.ToArray()) :
            domain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
            new System.Reflection.AssemblyName(nameModule),
            accessModule);
        // create module
        m_MainModule = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_AssemblyFileName)) ?
            m_MainBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(m_MainBuilder.GetName().Name, m_AssemblyFileName, true) :
            m_MainBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(m_MainBuilder.GetName().Name, true);
        // create properties storage
        Properties = new Dictionary<string, PropertyTypeInfo>();
    }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw (new Exception(ex.Message));
        }
}

public Type CreateInstance(string className, System.Reflection.TypeAttributes typeAccess)
{
    Type result = null;
    try
    {
        // create class
        System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder typeBuilder = m_MainModule.DefineType("System.Spyrytus.DynamicBuilder." + className, typeAccess);
        // create constructor
        System.Reflection.Emit.ConstructorBuilder cBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineConstructor(System.Reflection.MethodAttributes.Public, System.Reflection.CallingConventions.Standard, Type.EmptyTypes);
        // create event
        System.Reflection.Emit.FieldBuilder eventField =
            typeBuilder.DefineField("PropertyChanged",
            (!UsePropertyChangedEventHandler) ? typeof(PropertyChangedValueEventHandler) : typeof(System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler),
            System.Reflection.FieldAttributes.Private);
        // create event :D
        System.Reflection.Emit.EventBuilder eventBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineEvent(
            "PropertyChanged",
            System.Reflection.EventAttributes.None,
typeof(System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler));
        // add event handler
        eventBuilder.SetAddOnMethod(CreateAddRemoveMethodsEvent(typeBuilder, eventField, true));
        // remove handler
        eventBuilder.SetRemoveOnMethod(CreateAddRemoveMethodsEvent(typeBuilder, eventField, false));
        // handler
        System.Reflection.Emit.MethodBuilder raise = CreateRaisePropertyChanged(typeBuilder, eventField);
        eventBuilder.SetRaiseMethod(raise);

        // create property
        List<System.Reflection.Emit.PropertyBuilder> fields = CreatePropery(ref typeBuilder, cBuilder.GetILGenerator(), raise);

        System.Reflection.Emit.MethodBuilder toStrMethod = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
            "ToString",
            System.Reflection.MethodAttributes.Public | System.Reflection.MethodAttributes.Virtual | System.Reflection.MethodAttributes.HideBySig | System.Reflection.MethodAttributes.ReuseSlot,
            typeof(string),
            Type.EmptyTypes);
        typeBuilder.DefineMethodOverride(toStrMethod, typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString"));
        System.Reflection.Emit.ILGenerator toStr = toStrMethod.GetILGenerator();
        // create StringBuilder in string
        System.Reflection.Emit.LocalBuilder retValue = toStr.DeclareLocal(typeof(StringBuilder));
        toStr.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Newobj, retValue.LocalType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
        toStr.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Stloc_S, retValue);
        System.Reflection.Emit.Label exception = toStr.BeginExceptionBlock();
        // read all property
        foreach (System.Reflection.Emit.PropertyBuilder piItem in fields)
        {
            // local variable
            System.Reflection.Emit.LocalBuilder local = toStr.DeclareLocal(piItem.PropertyType);
            // read value
            toStr.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            toStr.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Call, piItem.GetGetMethod());
            toStr.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Stloc_S, local);
            // create Format
            toStr.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ldloc_S, retValue);
            toStr.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ldstr, piItem.Name + ": {0}\r\n");
            toStr.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ldloc_S, local);
            toStr.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Box, piItem.PropertyType);
            toStr.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Callvirt, retValue.LocalType.GetMethod("AppendFormat", new Type[] { typeof(string), piItem.PropertyType }));
            toStr.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Pop);
        }
        toStr.BeginCatchBlock(typeof(Exception));
        toStr.EndExceptionBlock();
        // exit from method
        toStr.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ldloc_S, retValue);
        toStr.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Callvirt, retValue.LocalType.GetMethod("ToString", Type.EmptyTypes));
        toStr.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ret);

        // create type
        result = typeBuilder.CreateType();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw (new Exception(ex.Message));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Create dynamic object:

```
using (Spyrytus.Windows.MSSQL.DynamicProxy proxy = new Spyrytus.Windows.MSSQL.DynamicProxy("module", System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save, "object.dll", attrs))
{
    proxy.CreateInstance("Foo", System.Reflection.TypeAttributes.Public);
    proxy.Save();
}
```

Add this DLL in refrences by right-click mouse, and try use it:

```
System.Spyrytus.DynamicBuilder.Foo t = new System.Spyrytus.DynamicBuilder.Foo()
```

And error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'module, Version=6.11.395.610, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Could not found special file.
```

What is it means ?

### Thanks In Advance.

Regards: Eugene.

Comment: You should make sure you tag the language too.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite worth to investigate your EXE with Dependency Walker utility http://www.dependencywalker.com

It will advise you which modules are actually imported into your EXE (so they must be available to run your EXE). Could you show which imports are found by Dependency Walker?

Comment: But when I load by: Assembly.LoadFile("module.dll") - work very well ... Why ?